# Local module not importing when Node.js project deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm able to import `myModule` when my project is running locally. However, when I push my project to Heroku, I run in to trouble importing myModule.

I get the error `TypeError: myModule.myFunc is not a function`. When I output the module to the console I get `{}`. However, when I import the file from the same directory, everything is fine. Additionally, I'm able to import other modules from its directory.

I'm importing with the below syntax and everything is cased properly.

```
var myModule = require('../myModuleFolder/myModule.js');
```

Any insight into what about Heroku is triggering this?